# FTP on Linux RH -- stuck at 150 Ascii

Tags: rhel, ftp

We have 2 linux RH servers, that were configured the same way. Same OS version, same ftp client, etc.

The ftp client that we had installed is located in this website.

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20810117/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/ftp-0.17-53.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

The permissions were already set up equally at a firewall level, for both servers. Both are on the same vlan 10.240.194.x/23

We have server A and B.

Server A connects to the ftp server withouth issues, we just have to set it up in active connection.

Server B does connect as well and we set it up in active mode. But when we try to list files/directories, find current dir location, or upload/download files we can't. So far the only thing we are able to do, is change to another directory.

Everytime we try, to do at least a simple ls,pwd we get this msg

```
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.    #It gets stuck here for a while. 
500 Command not understood.
```

As far as I understand, that ftp client, which is installed in both servers, doesn't have anything to be changed or configured.

Does anyone has an idea of what could be check/change to make the other server work.  Sadly the FTP server, is not owned by our company. I tried to do some search, but haven't been lucky.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're setting up an FTP server in 2017?  It's almost, but not quite, as outmoded a server infrastructure as telnet.

Comment: The client decided to receive the files from the Linux server, through FTP. So it wasn't up to us, neither the ftp server is from us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do FTP in passive mode and not active mode.

If using a text client, you have to use the command:

```
PASV
```

If using another piece of software, you will have to find the menu for PASSIVE mode transmission.

see [Active FTP vs. Passive FTP, a Definitive Explanation](http://www.slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem with SELinux. 
Run the `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on` command as the root user to enable access to FTP home directories.

See https://www.certdepot.net/selinux-use-boolean-settings/

Comment: damned, the thing is that in order to disable it, we need to restart the server. Since its a production server that is 24x7 used, restarting can't be done, unless this is truly the problem or the server hangs completely. I find out that in the server that the ftp works, this SeLinux is disabled....

Comment: You can run `setsebool` without rebooting the server.

Comment: did as you said, still problem is not resolve. The server connects to the ftp as always but as soon as I do a ls or pwd, it stucks for a while with the message  " 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection." and then displays  "ftp: accept: Resource temporarily unavailable
550
500 Command not understood.
"   which is not true about the resource temporarily unavaiable, as the ftp is working fine and the other Linux server can connect and send files.

Comment: Make sure the directory has read and execute permissions for the user you are trying to log in as. Try chmod a+rx directory. Can you do a ls -l one level up from the directory you are trying to access?

Comment: You might want to restart the ftp server after trying the setbool command.